# parse cloud code job : delete rows that have been in DB for an hour

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, backend

I'm using parse as a mobile backend for an ios app I'm developing. I know its probably not a permanent solution but for what I'm doing right now it gives me good test results. I need to create a cloud code job which will remove all the rows with entries older than one hour in all of my databases besides one (this DB is just for the sake of having a backup of everything).I want to do this so client side devices can only query for things in the DB that are less than an hour old.  I have a "timestamp" on each entry which I was going to incorporate into a js function to first check If all the entries were indeed an hour or more old, and if they were, delete them. I've been doing some research and really havent been able to develop a js function that would do this (I have absolutely no js experience whatSoEver just obj c) from my understanding it would be something similar to this

```
    Parse.Cloud.job("deleteRows", function(request, status) {

      Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

      var query = new Parse.Query(//inverse of db i dont want to delete from); 
      query.each(function(//row in db?) {

       // delete here under parameters ?

      }).then(function() {

        status.success("rows deleted");
      }, function(error) {

        status.error("job incomplete");
      });
    });
```

if anyone could give me a hand I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use the example in https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide?language=JavaScript#jobs-writing ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to delete all entries? You can do a query to collect data within 1 hour old. I am not familiar with iOS development but this could help you with a hint:

https://www.parse.com/questions/query-for-objects-created-in-the-past-20-minutes-and-the-opposite